# What's the current state of the art regarding algorithms for the singular value decomposition?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, svd

I'm working on a header-only matrix library to provide some reasonable degree of linear algebra capability in as simple a package as possible, and I'm trying to survey what the current state of the art is re: computing the SVD of a complex matrix.

I'm doing a two-phase decomposition, bidiagonalization followed by singular value computation.  Right now I'm using the householder method for the bidiagonalization (I believe LAPACK uses this as well), and I think that's about as good as it gets currently (unless someone knows of an $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$ algorithm for it..).

The singular value computation is next on my list, and I'm somewhat out of the loop on what the common algorithms are for doing this.  I read [here](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~dongarra/etemplates/node193.html) that research was heading towards a inverse-iteration method that guarantees orthogonality with $\mathcal{O}(N)$ complexity.  I'd be interested in hearing about that or other advances.

Comment: is there doc for your header-only matrix lib (apart from the .h) ?  Also please add tag "svd".

Answer (score 6):

"Randomized algorithms" have recently become quite popular for partial svds. A header only implementation can be downloaded here: http://code.google.com/p/redsvd/

A review of the current methods can be found here: http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4061

For full svds I am not sure if you can do better than Householder.

Comment: That sounds very interesting, I'll have to take a look at that survey paper, thanks!

Comment: OP is interested in algorithms for dense matrices. I don't think randomized algorithms are competitive in that setting, if they work at all.

Comment: This post indicated that randomized methods work just fine on dense matrices https://research.facebook.com/blog/294071574113354/fast-randomized-svd/

Comment: @dranxo There are no accuracy comparisons at all on that post, and the timing results do not look very meticulous. Also, randomized algorithms are based on projection + exact solution of a small-scale problem. This means OP would need an implementation of a "standard method" for the resulting small-scale problem anyway.

Comment: Fair enough. Though I am a bit confused why we should think that these methods only work on sparse matrices. Right out the abstract of Joel Tropp's paper: "For a dense input matrix, randomized algorithms require O(mn log(k))
floating-point operations (flops) in contrast with O(mnk) for classical algorithms." http://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.4061v2.pdf

Comment: You are right, "dense" was a bit of a misnomer. What I really meant is that OP seems to be focusing on that family of $O(n^3)$-time, $O(n^2)$-space algorithms suitable for small-scale matrices (up to about $n\approx 1000$), such as the ones in LAPACK. Large-scale computations are entirely a different beast.

Answer (score 4):

> I read [here](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~dongarra/etemplates/node193.html) that research was heading towards a inverse-iteration method that guarantees orthogonality with $\mathcal{O}(N)$ complexity.  I'd be interested in hearing about that or other advances.

(I wanted to just make a few comments since I don't have the time to write out details, but it got rather big for the comment box.)

That I believe would be the [MRRR (multiple relatively robust representations) algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/1186785.1186788) of Dhillon and Parlett. This is rooted in previous work by Fernando, which in turn was inspired by a problem posed by Jim Wilkinson in his monumental book on eigenvalue problems. The "inverse iteration" portion for obtaining singular vectors is rooted in the concept of ["twisted factorizations" by Fernando](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795%2897%2980053-5), which make use of factoring matrices into $\mathbf L\mathbf D\mathbf L^\top$ and $\mathbf U\mathbf D\mathbf U^\top$ decompositions.

The "singular value" portion of the algorithm, on the other hand, comes from the [(shifted) differential quotient difference (dqd(s)) algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795%2800%2900010-0), which is a culmination of previous work by [Fernando, Parlett](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s002110050024), [Demmel and Kahan](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0911052) (with inspiration from Heinz Rutishauser).

As you might know SVD methods usually proceed with a bidiagonal decomposition first before the singular values are obtained from the bidiagonal matrix. Unfortunately I'm not too updated on the current best method for the front-end bidiagonal decomposition; last I checked, the usual method is to start with QR decomposition with column pivoting and then apply orthogonal transformations appropriately to the triangular factor to finally obtain the bidiagonal decomposition.

I understand that I've been skimpy with the details; I'll try to flesh out this answer further once I have access to my library...

Comment: Matrix to bi-diagonal form, do a column then a row, repeat down the diagonal: use givens or householder to zero the column up to the diagonal, then do the same for the row to the super-diagonal.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I was thinking tri-diagonal form. Sorry. Bi-diagonalization is not trivial in a similarity (it would actually reveal the eigenvalues), but your reference is not doing a similarity, it is doing something else; left and right multiply with different orthogonal matrices. $UAV$ is bi-diagonal with $UU^\top=I$ and $VV^\top=I$, which can be done as you say with QR first, but not so easily described in a comment. I might be interested if you do flesh out the answer further (but I could also figure it out since my studies are headed this direction at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

There are the PROPACK and nu-TRLan libraries.

http://soi.stanford.edu/~rmunk/PROPACK/

http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~kewu/trlan/

Comment: Here, the poster is asking for algorithms, rather than libraries; could you instead talk about the algorithms being used in these libraries, their computational complexity, and why these libraries are state-of-the-art?