# Using algebraically smallest eigenvalues to find smallest in magnitude eigenvalues

Tags: eigensystem

I have a symmetric indefinite matrix, $H$. I also have a routine that can compute the algebraically smallest eigenvalues of a symmetric indefinite matrix. I would like to compute the eigenvalues with smallest magnitude using my existing code.

One way I can do this is to use my routine to compute the algebraically smallest eigenpairs of $H^2$. Then I can use Rayleigh quotients to figure the smallest magnitude eigenvalues of $H$. This works great but is very slow since $cond(H^2) = cond(H)^2$.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What does "algebraically smallest" mean?

Comment: from his way of currently solving it one can infer that it means "absolutely smallest"

Comment: By algebraically smaller I mean closer to $-\infty$. I don't know the proper term.

Comment: What you say here is just termed ''smallest'' (in your case = most negative). You'd get this by running the Lanczos algorithm. But the smallest eigenvalue of H^2 gives you the eigenvalue closest to 0 (the absolutely smallest), not to -infty, so I inferred that you meant that. So what do you really mean? If the spectrum were 2,1,-2,-5, which eigenvalue should be returned?

Comment: The current code will return -5. I would like a way to get 1.

Answer (score 5):

If you can afford a single factorization of $H$ you can find the absolute largest eigenvalue of $H^{-1}$ by the Lanczos algorithm, using the factorization to calculate matrix-vector products with $H^{-1}$. The inverse then gives the absolutely smallest eigenvalue of $H$.

Comment: Yes, inverse iteration can do it. Problem is that the bare bones matrix library I'm using does not have a linear solver and it's nontrivial to code up a good one that can handle indefinite matrices.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jacobi-Davidson to find the lowest eigenvalue(s). Also see [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1681/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-calculate-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-general-matrix) for related issues.